# Evaluate a Nested Integral

Tags: integration

According to two questions [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33442/series-of-nested-integrals) and [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489272/simplify-nested-dependent-integral) asked on this site earlier there exists a nice relation:

$$\frac1{n!} \left(\int_{0}^t\mathrm dt \; f(t)\right)^n = \int_{0}^t\mathrm dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1}\mathrm dt_2 \cdots \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}}\mathrm dt_n\; f(t_1)\,f(t_2) \ldots f(t_n). $$

Unfrotunatly I am more interested in integrals of the form

$$\int_{0}^t\mathrm dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1}\mathrm dt_2 \cdots \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}}\mathrm dt_n\; f(t_n). $$

Can it be somehow brought to an unary integral?

All I have figured out by now is that

$$\int_{0}^t\mathrm dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1}\mathrm dt_2 \cdots \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}}\mathrm dt_n\; t_n^m = \frac{m!}{(m+n)!} t^{m+n} .$$

Comment: Are you writing the $\mathrm dt$ before the expression you're integrating over? Or what it this?

Comment: @Darksonn The physicists often write the differential before the integrand for a few reasons, though such notation is never used in mathematics.

Comment: Unary integral, you means something like this?
$$\int_{0}^t\mathrm dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1}\mathrm dt_2 \cdots \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}}\mathrm dt_n\; f(t_n) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^t (t-t_n)^{n-1} f(t_n) \mathrm dt_n$$

Comment: @achillehui yes, you can make it into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f$ is integrable on $[0,t]$, we have

$$\int_{0}^t\mathrm dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1}\mathrm dt_2 \cdots \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}}\mathrm dt_n\; f(t_n) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^t (t-t_n)^{n-1} f(t_n) \mathrm dt_n$$

We can prove this using induction. Assume above statement is true up to a particular $n$, we have

$$\int_0^t\mathrm dt_1 \int_0^{t_1}\mathrm dt_2 \cdots \int_0^{t_{n}}\mathrm dt_{n+1}\; f(t_{n+1}) 
= \int_0^t \mathrm dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_{n+1} \frac{(t_1 - t_{n+1})^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f(t_{n+1})\\
= \int_0^t \left(\int_{t_{n+1}}^t dt_1 \frac{(t_1 - t_{n+1})^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \right) f(t_{n+1}) dt_{n+1}
= \int_0^t \frac{(t-t_{n+1})^n}{n!} f(t_{n+1}) dt_{n+1}
$$
i.e. the statement will also be true for $n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{1}\int_{0}^{t_{1}}\dd t_{2}\cdots\int_{0}^{t_{n - 1}}
\dd t_{n}\,\fermi\pars{t_{1}}\fermi\pars{t_{2}}\ldots\fermi\pars{t_{n}}}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{1}\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{2}\cdots\int_{0}^{t}
\dd t_{n}\,\Theta\pars{t_{1} - t_{2}}\Theta\pars{t_{2} - t_{3}}
\ldots\Theta\pars{t_{n - 1} - t_{n}}
\fermi\pars{t_{1}}\fermi\pars{t_{2}}\ldots\fermi\pars{t_{n}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over n!}\sum_{P\braces{t_{i}}}
\\[3mm]&\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{1}\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{2}\cdots\int_{0}^{t}
\dd t_{n}\,\Theta\pars{t_{1} - t_{2}}\Theta\pars{t_{2} - t_{3}}
\ldots\Theta\pars{t_{n - 1} - t_{n}}
\fermi\pars{t_{1}}\fermi\pars{t_{2}}\ldots\fermi\pars{t_{n}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\sum_{P\braces{t_{i}}}}$ means *sum over all permutations of*
$\ds{\braces{t_{1},t_{2},\ldots,t_{n}}}$.

> Then,
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{1}\int_{0}^{t_{1}}\dd t_{2}\cdots\int_{0}^{t_{n - 1}}
> \dd t_{n}\,\fermi\pars{t_{1}}\fermi\pars{t_{2}}\ldots\fermi\pars{t_{n}}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{1}\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{2}\cdots\int_{0}^{t}
> \dd t_{n}\,
> \\[3mm]&\underbrace{\ \bracks{%
> \sum_{P\braces{t_{i}}}\Theta\pars{t_{1} - t_{2}}\Theta\pars{t_{2} - t_{3}}
> \ldots\Theta\pars{t_{n - 1} - t_{n}}}\ }_{\ds{=\ 1}}\
> \fermi\pars{t_{1}}\fermi\pars{t_{2}}\ldots\fermi\pars{t_{n}}
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over n!}\bracks{\int_{0}^{t}\fermi\pars{t}\,\dd t}^{n}
> \quad\mbox{because}\quad
> \fermi\pars{t_{i}}\fermi\pars{t_{j}}=\fermi\pars{t_{j}}\fermi\pars{t_{i}}\,,\
> \forall\ i,j = 1,2,\ldots,n
> \end{align}

Comment: @achillehui Sorry. Sometimes we do not read completely a question. I'll delete this one in 24 hours such that it gives you a room to read this comment. Thanks.